# Repeated Summation function

Tags: notation, summation

I am writing a solution to a question, and the solution requires a lot of $\sum$ functions, is there a way to notate many $\sum$ functions in a row? for example is there one function that can simplify: $$\sum_{x=0}^n\left(\sum_{y=0}^{n-x} \frac{n!}{x!y!(n-x-y)!}\times a^xb^yc^{n-x-y} \right) $$into possibly just one function?

Comment: I don't think there is, but you might be able to use $\prod$ if you rewrite your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple summations (especially when the number of summation symbols depends on some variable) are commonly denoted with a single summation sign, where the list of constraints and dummy variables is given under the sign. For example, I could write your example as:

$$\sum_{0\le x\le n;0\le y\le n-x}\frac{n!}{x!y!(n-x-y)!}a^xb^yc^{n-x-y}$$

or more eloquently, changing $x\mapsto i$, $y\mapsto n-j$:

$$\sum_{0\le i\le j\le n}\frac{n!}{i!(n-j)!(j-i)!}a^ib^{n-j}c^{j-i}$$

or even (letting $z=n-x-y$, so that now we have a triple summation; the constraints of $x,y,z$ being nonnegative integers is implicit):

$$\sum_{x+y+z=n}\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}a^xb^yc^z$$

Comment: Thanks so much that is just what i needed :)